# Error in import mysql localhost to host

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to the transfer my Localhost Sql to hostonline , but I am facing this error.

How to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: I usually remove all of those comments.

Comment: Just delete the line in the SQL-file.